# Selecting a row in SQL (Snowflake) based on String

Tags: sql, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, partition

So I have a toughie here I've been wracking my brain on for a while.

Let's say I have a table as follows:

```
ID      Group                 Timestamp   Data
001         A   2021-04-13 12:51:12.063   content121
001  A-Direct   2021-04-13 12:52:13.063   content121
002  A-Direct   2021-04-13 12:50:14.063   content133
003  B-Direct   2021-04-13 12:55:12.063   content132
003         B   2021-04-13 12:56:11.063   content142
003        BA   2021-04-13 12:57:22.063   content153
004         D   2021-04-13 12:10:23.063   content113
004         C   2021-04-13 12:11:43.063   content144
005         C   2021-04-13 12:12:12.063   content111
005         A   2021-04-13 12:13:23.063   content100
005  D-Direct   2021-04-13 12:15:23.063   content121
006         A   2021-04-13 12:51:12.063   content121
006  B-Direct   2021-04-13 12:52:13.063   content121
007  A-Direct   2021-04-13 12:51:12.063   content121
007         A   2021-04-13 12:52:13.063   content121
008  B-Direct   2021-04-13 12:55:12.063   content132
008         B   2021-04-13 12:56:11.063   content142
008  B-Direct   2021-04-13 12:57:22.063   content153
009  B-Direct   2021-04-13 12:55:12.063   content132
009  C-Direct   2021-04-13 12:56:11.063   content142
009  D-Direct   2021-04-13 12:57:22.063   content153
```

So I need a table which contains one distinct ID as each row. But the selection criteria on which ID makes it is a little complicated.

**The default selection should be the most recent entry, selected via `TIMESTAMP`.**

But the complexity comes from any ID's that have rows with `-Direct`. Specifically, if a row has more than one entry and one is (for example) `A` and the other is `A-Direct`, we need the `A`. This is only the case when the letter matches. As seen in the case for `ID = 006`, we want `B-Direct` since its counterpart is `A`.

So at it's core the logic I am looking for is

**If an ID has rows beginning with the same string, and one of them ends in `-Direct`, substitute it with the `-Direct` removed.**

Final Output:

```
ID      Group
001         A
002  A-Direct
003        BA
004         C
005  D-Direct
006  B-Direct
007         A
008         B
009  D-Direct
```

For added clarity, here is an outline of what happened to each ID:

- ID 001: `A` is followed by `A-Direct` so we sub `A-Direct` for `A`
- ID 002: `A-Direct` is the only result, easy!
- ID 003: `BA`,`B`, `B-Direct` are distinct, therefore we stick with the most recent, `BA`.
- ID 004: No direct, so we just take the most recent, `C`
- ID 005: `D-Direct` is the most recent, but because there is no `D` , we stick with `D-Direct`
- ID 006: `B-Direct` is the most recent, but because there is no `B` , we stick with `B-Direct`
- ID 007: `A-Direct` is followed by `A` so we simply take the most recent one, no problem.
- ID 008: `B`and `B-Direct` (x2) appear here, therefore we can use `B`.
- ID 009: All options are Direct, so we go with the most recent, `D-Direct`

I can figure out how to get the most recent, but with the above criteria, I am unsure how to adjust

```
WITH data AS (
    select d.*,
        rank() over (
            partition by ID
            order by TIMESTAMP DESC
        ) as num
    FROM table d
)
select ID, TIMESTAMP
    from data
    where num = 1
```

Comment: Can there be more than one *-direct entry per id? Or multiple rows with same group per id?

Comment: @EdmCoff, yes! See ID 008, there are two B-Direct's. But both become lower priority to the B. I also added an ID 009 to further illustrate. If there are two different group's on the Direct for the same ID (B-Direct AND C-Direct) or (B-Direct AND B-Direct) then it's just the most recent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might start with something like the following. It isn't super-pretty so there might be a better solution, but I think it does what you want.

```
WITH data AS (
    select d.*,
        rank() over (
            partition by ID
            order by TIMESTAMP DESC
        ) as num
    FROM table d
)
select ID, 
 CASE 
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.id = d.id AND t.group || '-Direct' = d.group) 
   THEN replace(d.group, '-Direct') 
   ELSE d.group 
 END group
    from data d
    where num = 1
```

This gets the most recent one for each id (using your current code), but the `case`/`exists` statement in the `select` clause checks whether there is a match without "-Direct" and, if so, we remove the "-Direct" from the string.

Comment: this isnt exactly working for my data. What does || do?

Comment: The `||` is equivalent to `concat`. So `t.group || '-Direct' = d.group` is checking if there is a t.group (e.g. "B") that matches a d.group (e.g. "B-Direct")

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
SELECT ID
   ,CASE WHEN MIN(group) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, REPLACE(group, '-Direct'))
             = MAX(group) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, REPLACE(group, '-Direct'))
         THEN group
         ELSE REPLACE(group, '-Direct')
    END AS grp
FROM tab
QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) = 1;
```

Qualify ensures to take the lastest value per timestamp, and case expression handles '-Direct' override.